# ¿Cómo obtener usuarios github con fetch javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, github, ecmascript-6

¿cómo están? Tengo este problema a la hora de traer los usuarios desde github mediante fetch, quizás alguien pueda darme una mano, el problema que tengo es que las imágenes salen repetidas a la hora de imprimirlos en el dom, lo que quiero es que dentro de las img salga un usuario y luego en la otra salga otro usuario diferente, espero se entienda, muchas gracias.

```js
async function getAvatarPhoto(names) {  
    let jobs = [];

    for (let name of names) {
        let job = fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`).then(
                successResponse => {
                    if (successResponse.status != 200) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return successResponse.json();
                    }
                },
                failResponse => {
                    return null;
                }
            )
            .then((myJson) => {
                let avatar = myJson.avatar_url;
                let img2 = document.querySelector("#images .img2");
                let img3 = document.querySelector("#images .img3");
                img2.src = avatar;
                img3.src = avatar;
                console.log(avatar);
            })           

        jobs.push(job);
    }

    let results = await Promise.all(jobs);

    return results;
}


console.log(getAvatarPhoto(["agustinven", "KlausPost"]));
```

```html
       <article id="cuerpo-web">
            <div id="images">
                <img src="/img/tesla-roadster-2020-2017_05-nestandard1.jpg" alt="tesla" class="img2">
                <img src="/img/tesla_roadster_20.jpeg" alt="tesla" class="img3">
            </div>
   
        </article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se encuentra al momento de mostrar la información, mas especifico en estas dos lineas (en realidad es un problema de lógica)

```
img2.src = avatar;
img3.src = avatar;
```

porque siempre sobre escribirá la ultima llamada `ajax` a las imágenes del anterior usuario, existen infinitas formas de solucionarlo, yo lo hice de la siguiente forma cambie el html y para eso utilice la etiqueta `[template][1]`

```
<template id="modeloTag">
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <figure>
            <img src="" alt="tesla" class="img2">
            <figcaption>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </fieldset>

</template>
```

y el script que cambie

```
.then((myJson) => {
    let avatar = myJson.avatar_url
    // en esta linea
    let $template = document.querySelector('#modeloTag')
    $template.content.querySelector('.img2').src = avatar
    $template.content.querySelector('legend').textContent = myJson.login
    $template.content.querySelector('figcaption').textContent = myJson.name
    document.querySelector('#cuerpo-web').append(document.importNode($template.content, true))
    console.log(avatar)
  })
```

de esta forma siempre que se realice un peticion se insertara nuevo `html`

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias, me funciono, pero por otro lado se crearon dos fieldset y copiaron todo el contenido por dos jaj quedando uno arriba del otro, yo tenia mas codigo html ademas del que pase de ejemplo y ahora como que se duplico dos veces jaja, de todas formas me diste la solucion a este problema, GRACIAS.